# How to perform a vector overlay of two SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects?

Tags: r, gis, spatial, topology

I have two GIS layers -- call them `Soils` and `Parcels` -- stored as `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`s (`SPDF`s), and I would like to "overlay" them, [in the sense described here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/Gp_ToolRef/geoprocessing/overlay_analysis.htm).

The result of the overlay operation should be a new SPDF in which:

1. The `SpatialPolygons` component contains polygons formed by the intersection of the two layers. (Think all of the atomic polygons formed by overlaying two mylars on an overhead projector).
2. The `data.frame` component records the attributes of the `Soils` and `Parcels` polygons within which each atomic polygon falls.

**My question(s):** Is there an existing R function that does this? (I would even by happy to learn of a function that just gets the `SpatialPolygons` component right, calculating the atomic polygons formed from the intersection of the two layers.) I feel like **rgeos** should have a function that does (1) at least, but it seems not to...

Here is a figure that may help make it clearer what I'm after, followed by code that creates the `Soils` and `Parcels` layers shown in the figure.

[image]

```
library(rgeos)

## Just a utility function to construct the example layers.
flattenSpatialPolygons <- function(SP) {
    nm <- deparse(substitute(SP))
    AA <- unlist(lapply(SP@polygons, function(X) X@Polygons))
    SpatialPolygons(lapply(seq_along(AA),
                           function(X) Polygons(AA[X], ID=paste0(nm, X))))
}

## Example Soils layer
Soils <-
local({
    A <- readWKT("MULTIPOLYGON(((3 .5,7 1,7 2,3 1.5,3 0.5), (3 1.5,7 2,7 3,3 2.5,3 1.5)))")
    AA <- flattenSpatialPolygons(A)
    SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(AA,
           data.frame(soilType = paste0("Soil_", LETTERS[seq_along(AA)]),
                      row.names = getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(AA)))
})

## Example Parcels layer
Parcels <-
local({
    B <- readWKT("MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,2 0,2 3,0 3,0 0),(2 0,4 0,4 3,2 3,2 0)),((4 0,6 0,6 3,4 3,4 0)))")
    BB <- flattenSpatialPolygons(B)
    SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(BB,
           data.frame(soilType = paste0("Parcel_", seq_along(BB)),
                      row.names = getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(BB)))
})
```

Comment: `%over%` or `overlay`?  See also gis.SE and @Spacedman's cheat sheet: http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/cheatsheet.html

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- Thanks, but nope -- `over()` doesn't do what I'm after. Like I said, I need a function that returns the individual polygons, not just an indicator of whether they overlap. (Plus, even if I can construct the atomic polygons `over` et al. don't  help, becauses they count polygons sharing a border as being "over" one another. `rgeos::gRelate()` is better in that respect.)

Comment: gContains and gOverlaps then, followed by gIntersection?

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- Care to show me what you mean? A combo of `gIntersection` and `gSymdifference` is the closest I got before giving up and posting, but it doesn't get the atomic polygons (i.e. the 10 polygons in the bottom figure that containing no lines in them). This seems a pretty fundamental GIS operation, and I'll be happy to give a bounty to whoever shows me how to do it in R (or with a call to some other easily linked GIS)...

Comment: Crazy busy this week but hopefully the answer below will be enough to get you started.  Let me know if not and I'll try to do more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since January of 2014, the **raster** package includes a `union()` function that makes this easy-peasy:

```
library(raster)
Intersects <- Soils + Parcels  ## Shorthand for union(Soils, Parcels)

## Check that it work
data.frame(Intersects)
## soilType.1 soilType.2
## 1     Soil_A       <NA>
## 2     Soil_B       <NA>
## 3       <NA>   Parcel_1
## 4       <NA>   Parcel_2
## 5       <NA>   Parcel_3
## 6     Soil_A   Parcel_2
## 7     Soil_A   Parcel_3
## 8     Soil_B   Parcel_2
## 9     Soil_B   Parcel_3
plot(Intersects, col = blues9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since January 2014, the solution posted here has been completely superseded by the `raster::union()` function, demonstrated in the officially accepted answer above.

---

This gets the "atomic" polygons formed by overlaying two different `SpatialPolygons` layers, solving Part 1 of my question.

```
library(rgeos)

gFragment <- function(X, Y) {
    aa <- gIntersection(X, Y, byid = TRUE)
    bb <- gDifference(X, gUnionCascaded(Y), byid = T)
    cc <- gDifference(Y, gUnionCascaded(X), byid = T)
    ## Note: testing for NULL is needed in case any of aa, bb, or cc is empty,
    ## as when X & Y don't intersect, or when one is fully contained in the other
    SpatialPolygons(c(if(is.null(aa)) NULL else aa@polygons,
                      if(is.null(bb)) NULL else bb@polygons,
                      if(is.null(cc)) NULL else cc@polygons)) 
}

## Try it out
Fragments <- gFragment(Parcels, Soils)
plot(Fragments, col=blues9)
```

And this extracts the ids (if any) of the polygons in the two input layers overlain by each "atomic" polygon outputted by `gFragment()` above, solving part 2 of my question.

```
getAttributes <- function(Fragments, Layer1, Layer2, eps = 0) {
    ## Function to extract attributes from polygon layers
    ## overlain by fragments
    OVER <- function(AA, BB) {
        X <- gRelate(AA, BB, byid = TRUE, pattern="2********")
        ii <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(X)),
                    function(i) {
                        A <- which(X[,i])
                        if(!length(A)) NA else A
                    })
        rownames(X)[ii]
    }
    ## First need to (very slightly) trim Fragments b/c otherwise they
    ## tend to (very slightly) overlap adjacent ring(s)
    Frags <- gBuffer(Fragments, width = -eps, byid = TRUE)
    ## Construct data.frame of attributes
    df <- data.frame(OVER(Frags, Layer1), 
                     OVER(Frags, Layer2),
                     row.names = names(Fragments))
    names(df) <- c(deparse(substitute(Layer1)), deparse(substitute(Layer2)))
    ## Add data.frame to SpatialPolygons object
    SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Fragments, data=df)
}

FragmentsDF <- getAttributes(Fragments = Fragments,
                             Layer1 = Parcels,
                             Layer2 = Soils)

## A few ways to examine the results
data.frame(FragmentsDF, row.names=NULL)
#   Parcels Soils
# 1      B2    A1
# 2      B2    A2
# 3      B3    A1
# 4      B3    A2
# 5      B1  <NA>
# 6      B2  <NA>
# 7      B3  <NA>
# 8    <NA>    A1
# 9    <NA>    A2
spplot(FragmentsDF, zcol="Soils", col.regions=blues9[3:4])
spplot(FragmentsDF, zcol="Parcels", col.regions=grey.colors(3))
```

**Edit:**

Note that this code may fail if any of your input polygons have id's named `"1"`. In that case, one workaround is to rename the id's, perhaps by doing something like `Parcels <- spChFIDs(Parcels, paste0("pp", row.names(Parcels)))`.

Comment: @mdsumner Thanks. **rgeos** is pretty nifty, 'enit?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my crack, this just gives a list of the pieces with the Parcel (Parcels->Soils) data. You still need to get the attributes from the Soils object, and then do a similar job with the "differences", and then vice versa (Soils->Parcels) so you can have any kinds of overlap relations.

```
intersects <- list()

## find all intersections (NULLs do nothing to the result)
for (i in 1:nrow(Soils)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(Parcels)) {
    intersects[[sprintf("%sx%s", i, j)]] <- gIntersection(Soils[i,],
                                                          Parcels[j,]) 
  }
}

result <- list()
## let's try Parcels, transfer data attributes to new pieces
for (i in 1:nrow(Parcels)) {
  for (j in seq_along(intersects))
   if(gContains(Parcels[i,], intersects[[j]])) {
     result <- c(result, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(intersects[[j]],     as.data.frame(Parcels[i,]), match.ID = FALSE))

   }
}


## plot
plot(Parcels, xlim = range(c(bbox(Parcels)[1,], bbox(Soils[1,]))),
     ylim = range(c(bbox(Parcels)[2,], bbox(Soils[2,]))))
plot(Soils, add = TRUE)

cols <- colorRampPalette(c("lightblue", "darkblue"))(length(result))
for (i in 1:length(result)) plot(result[[i]], col = cols[i], add = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(result)) text(coordinates(result[[i]]), label =     as.data.frame(result[[i]])[,"soilType"])
```

Comment: Lots of interesting ideas here. Thanks! I'll be using both your `sprintf()` and polygon labeling code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea (do this as a nested loop over parcels then over soils; I'm not sure it can be vectorized the way that the `g*` functions are written) :

```
i <- 2
j <- 2
pieces <- list()
pieces[["int"]] <- gIntersection(Parcels[i,],Soils[j,])
pieces[["diff1"]] <- gDifference(Parcels[i,],Soils[j,])
pieces[["diff2"]] <- gDifference(Soils[j,],Parcels[i,])
plot(Parcels)
plot(Soils,add=TRUE)
plot(pieces[["int"]],col="red",add=TRUE)
plot(pieces[["diff1"]],col="blue",add=TRUE)
plot(pieces[["diff2"]],col="green",add=TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

That should be enough to get you started.  The rest is just looping while keeping track of the pieces and merging them all into one big SPDF.

An alternative approach that's more vectorized is:

```
pieces <- list()
pieces[["int"]] <- gIntersection(Parcels,Soils,byid=TRUE)
pieces[["diff1"]] <- gDifference(Parcels,Soils,byid=TRUE)
pieces[["diff2"]] <- gDifference(Soils,Parcels,byid=TRUE)
```

This gives you more pieces than actually exist, for some reason.  Then you'll have to go back and rbind them and cull the extra pieces that are `gEquals`.

Comment: Hi Ari -- thanks a bunch for engaging with this problem, but this doesn't do what I need. Neither the blue nor the green polygons are among the atomic polygons that I want (i.e. the 10 shaded regions in my bottom figure). (I got that figure, by the way, by doing something similar to your suggestion, using a combination of `gIntersection(Soils, Parcels, byid=TRUE)` and `gSymdifference(Soils, Parcels, byid=TRUE)`: the `byid` argument avoids a bunch/all of the looping you refer to. But the fundamental problem is that that code too gives me polygons other than the ones I want.)

Comment: I think if you do it recursively it still does what you want.  E.g. the green poly gets intersected with Soils[1,], which splits it further into the pieces you want.  Not very elegant, but I think it still works, no?